# Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'DataSource' and 'DataSourceOptions'

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, typeorm

I am getting an error `Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'DataSource'.` and `Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'DataSourceOptions'.` while `nest build`.

After npm install I build my nestjs application with `nest build`command from command line, but I am getting these errors.

typeorm version is "^0.2.25", and "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",

Cannot figure out why it is happening.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "incremental": true,
    "typeRoots": ["types", "node_modules/@types"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "scripts", "dist"]
}
```

ormconfig.ts

```
const DATABASE_TYPE = process.env.DATABASE_TYPE || 'postgres';
const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const DATABASE_SSL =
  process.env.DATABASE_SSL !== undefined ? process.env.DATABASE_SSL === 'true' : true;
const DATABASE_SSL_CA = process.env.DATABASE_SSL_CA;

const root = __dirname;

export default {
  type: DATABASE_TYPE,
  url: DATABASE_URL,
  schema: 'qcxapp',
  entities: [`${root}/**/*.entity.{js,ts}`, `${root}/**/*.model.{js,ts}`],
  migrations: [`${root}/database/migrations/*.{js,ts}`],
  synchronize: false,
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: `${root}/database/migrations`,
  },
  seeds: [`${root}/**/*.seed.{js,ts}`],
  factories: [`${root}/**/*.factory.{js,ts}`],
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
  ssl: DATABASE_SSL_CA ? { ca: DATABASE_SSL_CA, rejectUnauthorized: false } : DATABASE_SSL,
};
```

Comment: Show your tsconfig.json

Comment: @DaveMeehan I have updated the question and added tsconfig.json.

Comment: Can u show your orm config as well?

Comment: @n1md7 I have added orm config.

Comment: afaik `DataSource` is introduced in v0.3, Are you sure the installed TypeORM version is definitely v0.2.25?

Comment: The [Nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm) examples shows using DataSource, and doesn't mention anything about version compatibility, but suggests that typeorm should be installed without version specifics (`npm install typeorm`).  Looks like your packages just need updating to latest.

Comment: @n1md7 I have checked the package-lock.json the version installed is 0.2.25

Comment: installing with 0.3.0 the error now disappeared

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this error by specifying fixed package versions:

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "8.0.2",
"typeorm": "0.2.45",
```

Comment: Should this be typeorm instead of typeform?

Comment: Should  be typeorm, typo fixed, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by removing the typeorm and then adding it again.
use the commands:

```
yarn remove typeorm
```

later

````
yarn add typeorm
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Do `nest i` (`npx nest i` for server) look for typeorm version if it's not 8.0.2 DO

```
yarn remove @nestjs/typeorm
```

then

```
yarn add @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.2
```

then check the nest info again with `nest i` (`npx nest i` for server)
if typeorm version is 8.0.2 problem should disappear